# Align an image left and right of paragraph in div bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to align each image to the left and right of the text in the "wrapper2 panel-footer center-block" div. It correctly aligns the left image, but the right image is actually going "under" the div for some reason.

```css
.wrapper2 {
  max-width: 800px;
  float: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper2 panel-footer center-block">
  <div class="pull-left">
    <img alt="logo" src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/miu-flat-social/60/stackoverflow-128.png" />
  </div>
  <p><small>Copyright &copy; All Rights Reserved.</small>
  </p>
  <div class="pull-right">
    <img alt="logo" src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/miu-flat-social/60/stackoverflow-128.png" />
  </div>
```

Any reason for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To align divs next to each other in Bootstrap you utilize columns. There are 12 columns in a row, so in the example below I put each element in a 4 wide using the `col-xs-4` class.

I also added the `img-responsive` class to both of the images so they scale down correctly on smaller devices.

```
<div class="wrapper2 panel-footer">
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="pull-left"><img class="img-responsive" alt="logo" src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/miu-flat-social/60/stackoverflow-128.png" /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <p><small>Copyright &copy; All Rights Reserved.</small></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">
    <div class="pull-right"><img class="img-responsive" alt="logo" src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/miu-flat-social/60/stackoverflow-128.png" /></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a working fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/88ebLj7e/

You can find more information on the Bootstrap grid here: https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Answer (score 0):

`<p>` Tag is outside the `pull-left` class. That's what made it looks "under" the div. When you use `pull-left`. all should be INSIDE the class.
From your codes, `<p><small>` belongs to `wrapper2` not `pull-left` or `pull-right`.

If you need more flexible usage, you can use what James Ives suggest. Otherwise, you should change it into like this:

**Add** one line in your stylesheet as follows:

```
<style>
.wrapper2 p{float:left; padding-left:30%;}
</style>

<div class="wrapper2 panel-footer center-block"> 
<div class="pull-left"><img alt="logo" src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/miu-flat-social/60/stackoverflow-128.png" /></div>
        <p><small>Copyright &copy; All Rights Reserved.</small></p>
<div class="pull-right"><img alt="logo" src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/miu-flat-social/60/stackoverflow-128.png" /></div>
</div>
```

So, what you need now is to decide `padding-left` value.
Hopes, it helps.